# Use Informix Database using Maven

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, informix

I have `Java Maven` project. I am running database queries against `Informix` Database but cannot find the `dependencies` for `Informix` Database.

I have tried

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.informix.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.com.informix.jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.JC3</version>
        </dependency>
```

But it is throwing

```
Missing artifact 
com.informix.jdbc:com.springsource.com.informix.jdbc:jar:3.0.0.JC3
```

Could someone help me using `Informix` from `Maven`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like [that dependency](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.com.informix.jdbc&version=3.0.0.JC3) is in Spring's enterprise bundle repository. If you haven't already, you'll need to add the following repository definitions in order to resolve it:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
    </repository>
<repositories>
```

Comment: Could you also tell me how did you find those repositories?

Comment: The prefix of `com.springsource.` on the `artifactId` jogged my memory of Spring's repositories. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following dependency in your pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.informix</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.10.6.20151104</version>
</dependency>
```